# How to dismiss SearchManager after search

Tags: java, android, android-searchmanager

how I am trying to dismiss the `SearchManager` in an android application after I finish fetching data, how I can do that?

for now I am touching the list view to hide the search bar and the keyboard.

http://www.ideasandroid.com/android/sdk/docs/images/search/search-suggest-custom.png

Comment: Are you fetching results autocomplete style or fetching on search button press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried calling stopSearch() after you've loaded your results?

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#stopSearch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#stopSearch%28%29)

Comment: I have read that document before but I could not figure out how to use it, I mean ***Object*** / ***Class***.stopSearch();, Do You have any idea?

Comment: SearchManager manager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE).

Comment: Thank you for the response I am not at the office right now, i will try it and let you know.

Comment: No probs, you might need to cast it... SearchManager manager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE)